# RapidMiner Get Day of the Week

Tags: date, timestamp, rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner to deal with a dataset that has a timestamp attribute. I am using the **Generate Attribute** operator to obtain the date from the timestamp:

```
date = date_parse([vr_timestamp])
```

However, I need to obtain the Day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, ...).

Any idea of how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following within `Generate Attributes`.

```
dayofweek = date_str_custom(aDate, "E")
```

In this case, `aDate` is an attribute of type `Date time` and `dayofweek` is your new attribute.

A full reference to all possible values that control this is given [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).